# Speeding up scraping using Python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, praw

I am working on a script that scrapes comments from Reddit using the `praw` module and applies sentiment analysis on the scraped content using `SentimentIntensityAnalyzer` from `nltk.sentiment`. Here is my function:

```
def analyze_keyword_reddit(keywords):

    results = reddit.subreddit("all").search(keywords, sort="comments", limit=None)

    all_posts = ""
    all_comments = 0
    all_upvotes = 0

    for post in results:
        all_comments += post.num_comments
        all_upvotes += post.score

        # get all posts for keyword
        submission = reddit.submission(id=post.id)
        submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0, threshold=10)

        posts = " ".join([post.body.lower() for post in submission.comments.list()])
        all_posts = all_posts + " " + posts

    polarity_scores = sia.polarity_scores(all_posts)

    return {**{'all_comments': all_comments, 'all_upvotes': all_upvotes}, **polarity_scores}
```

When analyzing the runtime of this function, more than 90% of runtime happens at the step which flattens comment trees (this line: `submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0, threshold=5)`). Sadly, I haven't found much on whether the runtime of this command can be significantly improved (beyond setting the `threshold` parameter and thus limiting the number of comments retrieved) so I began exploring the option of multiprocessing. Using the above function, I ran the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tic = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        print(p.starmap(analyze_keyword_reddit, ['$u unity stock','$fsly fastly stock','$ttcf tattooed chef stock']))
    toc = time.time()
```

and then, for comparison, I also ran the following one without multiprocessing:

```
tic = time.time()
for t in ['$u unity stock','$fsly fastly stock','$ttcf tattooed chef stock']:
    print(analyze_keyword_reddit(t))
toc = time.time()
print(f"Scraping without multiprocessing: {round(toc-tic,2)} seconds.")
```

The normal version took 128 seconds. The multiprocessing version, however, seems to have created four threads, evaluating the exact same input four times in parallel (this became apparent the moment I added a simple `print(keywords)` into `analyze_keyword_reddit()`). These four threads took 708, 727, 729, and 731 seconds respectively. Furthermore, the multiprocessing snippet seems to remain in an infinite loop - it didn't stop at the end of the third keyword.

Where am I wrong with my implementation? And am I on the right track with my objective to speed up the scraping process, or should I totally go with another implementation?

---

**Edit:**
Based on Ron Serruya's great reply below, I updated the code which now uses `map()` instead of `starmap()`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tic = time.time()
    with Pool() as p:
        print(p.map(analyze_keyword_reddit, ['$u unity stock','$fsly fastly stock','$ttcf tattooed chef stock']))
    toc = time.time()
    print(f"Scraping with multiprocessing: {round(toc-tic,2)} seconds.")
```

However, this time the process seems to not even start. The function `analyze_keyword_reddit` seems to never be evaluated. I added a print function right in the beginning of it and there is no output appearing on the terminal at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `map` instead of `starmap`

Starmap expects the args to be iterable, it then unpacks the iterable to the function

So `p.starmap(analyze_keyword_reddit, ["hello", "world"])`
Will call `analyze_keyword_reddit(['h','e','l','l','o'])` and `analyze_keyword_reddit(['w','o','r','l','d'])`

I can just assume it makes the Reddit library work harder

```py
In [1]: from multiprocessing import Pool

In [2]: with Pool() as p:
   ...:     p.starmap(print, ["hello", "world"])
   ...:
h e l l o
w o r l d

In [3]: with Pool() as p:
   ...:     p.map(print, ["hello", "world"])
   ...:
hello
world
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful input. I replaced `starmap` with `map` but this time the process doesn't even start. It seems the process halts and the function never gets evaluated. I updated my post.